# What is the function of max-width?

Tags: css

In this following code i can't understand the function of max-width?and my instructor have written:"It sets `max-width:1170px`, because when you add the left and right padding with the max-width, you get 1200px which is our large device breakpoint." I hope u can reply on me.Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for guidance on how to frame a question. I think you need to add some code to this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `max-width` property defines the maximum width of an element. This means that if the width is calculated dynamically, it will never exceed the `max-width` value, but it could be any value smaller.

In your instructors example, the `max-width` + the side `padding` will add up to the screen width. This ensures the maximum width of the element never exceeds the width of the screen.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot. You have really helped me as i'm still a beginner. :D

Answer (score 0):

### max-width

**The max-width property in CSS is used to set the maximum width of a specified element.** The max-width property overrides the width property, but min-width will always override max-width whether followed before or after width in your declaration

Using max-width instead of width in this situation will improve the browser's handling of small windows.

This is important when making a site usable on mobile.

By the way, max-width is supported by all major browsers including IE7+ so you shouldn't be afraid of using it.

Comment: Hey @LasVegasCoder i would like to thank u for your comment but couldn't understand the following part **The max-width property overrides the width property, but min-width will always override max-width whether followed before or after width in your declaration** (copied).Could you tell me what u mean in another way?Thanks in advance :D

Comment: @MohamedAshraf When you set max-width it overrides width properties.